# ammap change individual country color from a group of countries on hover

Tags: amcharts, ammap

I have created a world map using the ammap concept, where individual countries have been grouped into a region using the "group_id". Now on hover over an individual country the whole region gets highlighted with a single color. Now my requirement is to highlight different countries of the region with different colors, still remaining in the group.
Any way to achieve this? Any other suggestions or links would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of hard work i finally got my answer. We can use the toggleMapObjectAlpha() to fill opacity for the individual countries.
The function:

```
map.addListener('init', function () {
      function toggleMapObjectAlpha(e) {
        var alpha = e.type=="rollOverMapObject"?.3:.8;
        e.event.target.setAttribute("fill-opacity",alpha);
      }
      map.addListener('rollOverMapObject',toggleMapObjectAlpha);
      map.addListener('rollOutMapObject',toggleMapObjectAlpha);
    });
```

For reference: http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/00Lgofbu/light/